# Using a database field containing SQL within a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a little help with a query I'm working on using SQL Server.

The query grabs search field information for specific categories and uses it to return a list of profiles which are ordered by the number of profiles within that category.

I need the query to run with the information contained within the wn.sqlcheck field.
Then order by sectionCount.

**The query**

```
SELECT wc.name,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM facilities WHERE wc.sqlcheck) AS sectionCount
FROM webcategories wc
WHERE wc.parentid = 1
ORDER BY sectionCount
```

**webcategories Example**

```
parentid | name           | sqlcheck 
-----------------------------------------
1        | categorytitle  | (highcaretotalnumberbeds > 0 AND highcaredoubleroomsyn = 1)
1        | categorytitle2 | (othernumberbeds > 0 AND otherdoubleroomsyn = 1)
```

---

### **I'm now using a stored proceedure**

```
SET @sqlcheck = (select sqlcheck from webcategories where parentid=1)

EXEC('SELECT wc.id, wc.name,
   (SELECT count(id) FROM facilities WHERE '+@sqlcheck+') AS sectionCount
FROM webcategories wc
WHERE wc.parentid = 1
ORDER BY sectionCount')
```

This error occurs:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

This is because there's multiple rows returned from the subquery for parentid = 1.

### **I still require help on how to loop through all the results returned from the webcategories table. Much appreciated :)**

Comment: You cannot load a where clause dynamically like that. A stored procedure that builds/executes a new query using that field's value will work, but from a standard select query, not possible.

Comment: Where's the table for alias `wn`?

Comment: you shall use sp_execute for that

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use sp_execute for this? I've read a few resources on it an still not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to use **sp_executesql**. Detailed example can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.100).aspx.

Here is how to loop using a cursor (fast version of it):

```
DECLARE @catName varchar(100), @sqlCheck varchar(max)

DECLARE webcat_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
SELECT name, sqlcheck
FROM webcategories
WHERE parentId = 1
ORDER BY sectionCount

OPEN webcat_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM webcat_cursor
INTO @catName, @sqlCheck

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --the query to be executed
    --I have taken it from one of the answers
    EXEC('SELECT wc.' + @catName + ',
       (SELECT count(*) FROM facilities WHERE ' + @sqlCheck + ') AS sectionCount    
    FROM webcategories wc
    WHERE wc.parentid = 1
    ORDER BY sectionCount')
    --end of executed query

    FETCH NEXT FROM webcat_cursor 
    INTO @catName, @sqlCheck
END

CLOSE webcat_cursor
DEALLOCATE webcat_cursor
```

Comment: thanks Igor, any idea how to get the multiple results from the webcategories table, loop through them and check the number of matches in table facilities? (see edited orginal question)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
  declare  @name  varchar(100)
    set @name=(select name from webcategories where parentid=1 )
    declare  @sqlcheck  varchar(100)
    set @sqlcheck=(select sqlcheck from webcategories where parentid=1 )

    exec('SELECT wc.'+@name+',
       (SELECT count(*) FROM facilities WHERE '+@sqlcheck+') AS sectionCount
    FROM webcategories wc
    WHERE wc.parentid = 1
    ORDER BY sectionCount')
```

Comment: Getting there.
I've entered the procedure but now receiving this error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: see the sub query that is  returned  more than 1 value ie you condition is  highcaretotalnumberbeds > 0 AND highcaredoubleroomsyn = 1 not perfect.

Comment: and make  a try like manly                                    SELECT wc.categorytitle,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM facilities WHERE highcaretotalnumberbeds > 0 AND highcaredoubleroomsyn = 1) AS sectionCount                                                        
FROM webcategories wc 
WHERE wc.parentid = 1
ORDER BY sectionCount                                                            ,    if it work fine then you need to see the  sqlcheck and remove the '(',')' then try above.

Comment: I think the problem is that there's multiple results in my webcategories table that have the parentid 1. I need the query to loop through each of these results and get the corresponding number of results from the facilities table. I've updated the example in my original question.

Comment: @Ben you do as Igor Turman done, it will give output but the thing is it will give multiple result set.